# uiTableViewCell Add row with and image and remove row with second tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to figuered this out for hours. I'm just plain old stuck here. What im trying to accomplish is basically inserting a row directly below the row just tapped in the tableview in addition i would like to add and image to the row and and make the image clickable to respond to its click event.

So here is my code.
  I implemented (i belive) the nessesary methods  to handle all the actions for the uitableview. 
when the user taps the cell i handle that action by executing the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"running  line 225%@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }



    Locations *location = nil;
    Locations *tempObject = [[Locations alloc]init];




   //test to see if we are looking for the search box or if we are essentially looking from the main view controller.
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            location= [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"location : %@" ,location.locationName);


    } else {
            location = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"location : %@" ,location.locationName);
        //set the new indexpath to 1 more then before so that we can essetially add a row right below the actual tapped item.
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        indexPath = newPath;


        [self.locations insertObject:tempObject atIndex:indexPath.row ];


        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

        self.visibleCell =YES; //set this boolean variable so that we can add a specific row  image to this var
       // self.locations[0].isItVisible = YES;

    }//ends the else statement.


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



}
```

the above code inserts an empty cell into my tableview.
however how can i set the cell so that its custom and not the same as the others. In other words my initial cells data-source are basically bound to an nsobject and a string property location-name. However when i go try to update the table cells in the above method i obviously cannot add an image into a string so I'm running in to a error. 
 so i tried to instead make the update on the

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

by basically checking if a variable is set to true or false but that turned out to be buggy because even when i scroll this method gets called.

How should i go about doing this. I think i have to do it all in the didselectrowindexaspath method. But i cant figured out how to change the newly inserted cell to contain an image only. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
here is what im doing to try to add the image under the `cellforrowindexpath` method.

```
if(self.visibleCell==YES){
        UIImage *clkImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_clock.png"];

        cell.imageView.image = clkImg;

    }
```

Im a noob so im not sure im doing this correctly.

**EDIT**
this is the full `cellforatindexpath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (debug==1) {
        NSLog(@"running line 159 %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
   // NSLog(@"cell for row at index path just got called");

    //JAMcustomCell *myCell = [[JAMcustomCell alloc]init];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    Locations * locations = [[Locations alloc]init];
    //tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // NSLog(@"this is visible '%hhd'", locations.isItVisible);
    if(self.visibleCell==YES){
        UIImage *clkImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_clock.png"];

        cell.imageView.image = clkImg;

    }




    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        locations  = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else{

        locations = [self.locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }


        cell.textLabel.text = locations.locationName;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];
  //  cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Graytbl.fw.png"]];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueTbl.fw.png"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueTbl.fw.png"]];
   // UIFont *myFont = [ UIFont fontWithName: @"Oswald" size: 25.0 ];
  //  cell.textLabel.font  = myFont;


    cell.textLabel.font= self.MyFont;//[UIFont fontWithName:@"Oswald-Regular.ttf" size:15];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using different cell identifiers ?

Comment: nope im not. would you like to see the post of my `cellforrowatindexpath`?

Comment: yes if you can post . i will try to help.

Comment: i updated the code to include the cell for index.

Comment: you should have a prototype/custom cell, that you return based on its identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, I used your idea of `Bool`

```
#pragma mark - Table View Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  self.numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.visibleCell){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];//ListPrototypeCell
        UIImageView *imageVIew = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        [imageVIew setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_clock.png"]];
        return cell;
    }else{
        return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

}



#pragma mark - Table View Delegate


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    if(!self.visibleCell){
        self.numberOfRows++;
        self.visibleCell = YES;
        NSIndexPath *indexPathCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }else{
        self.numberOfRows--;
        self.visibleCell = NO;
        NSIndexPath *indexPathCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

}
```

I created a demo [project](https://mega.co.nz/#!nYglgR6b!XS0owfX3zDcD_i_b5H0wDeygylbHJzRfwT62KbtqkzY) for you.

I hope it helps

Comment: meda if i could vote your response up twice i would. This is absolute genius i have look at example after example trying to figured out how to do this. I'm forever grateful for your answer and demo project. Thats exactly what i was trying to do. Just one last question how do i target just the height of the alarm clock cell with the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?